# ServerSelectionTimeoutError when connecting to aws with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssl, pymongo

I am attempting to connect to MongoDB hosted on an AWS instance with a key file. I am able to ssh into the instance and connect to the database with no issues. When I try to connect to the database from a remote location with pymongo I receive this error: 
 `ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: EOF occurred in violation of protocol`

Port 27017 is open and the source is set to 0.0.0.0/0.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://ec2-123-45-678-910.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 
                     27017, 
                     ssl=True, 
                     ssl_keyfile='/path_to/mykey.pem')

db = client.test
coll = db.foo
coll.insert_many(records)

ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277061/using-pymongo-to-connect-to-mongodb-on-aws-instance-from-windows) question is nearly identical to mine, however the error is different and the solution posted there does not apply to my issue.

The address and key here have been changed, I have been going in circles on this for hours with no luck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error sounds like the server or client is not configured to do SSL, maybe see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/

Comment: Is the `ssl_keyfile` param value the `pem` to the machine instance or to the MongoDB ? See [Configure MongoDB for TLS/SSL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/)

Answer (score 6):

This issue can cause because of following issue:

1. version of pymongo (suggest to use 3.3.0, which worked for me)
2. It can be a DNS issue, etc, in fact you could check for a DNS issue using:

telnet xx.xx.xx.xx port

3. can be a firewall issue
4. Can be an issue with ssl key. Try the following to test:

```
    import os
    
    import pymongo
    
    import ssl
    
    URL="url:port/db?ssl=true"
    
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(URL, ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
    
    db = client.get_default_database()
    
    print db
    
    print db.collection_names()
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (SSL handshake) with Pymongo module to connect to DocumentDB Azure (Data Base).

The error  :

`ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)`

I was using pymongo==3.4.0

**To resolve this :**

**Change the version of pymongo by installing the 3.3.0 version**

`pip install pymongo==3.3.0`

**Try:**

`import pymongo
pymongo.__version__`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that my Python setup only supported TLS 1.0 – not TLS 1.1 or above.

You can check it like this:

**Python 3**

```
> from urllib.request import urlopen
> urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read()
```

**Python 2**

```
> from urllib2 import urlopen
> urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read()
```

Check the output for the key `tls_version`. If it says `TLS 1.0` and not `TLS 1.1` or `TLS 1.2` that could be the problem.

If you're using a virtualenv, be sure to run the command inside.

### Solution: Install Python with a newer version of OpenSSL

In order support TLS 1.1 or above, you may need to install a newer version of OpenSSL, and install Python again afterwards. This should give you a Python that supports TLS 1.1.

The process depends on your operating system – here's a guide for [OS X](https://comeroutewithme.com/2016/03/13/python-osx-openssl-issue/).

**virtualenv users**
For me, the Python outside of my virtualenv had TLS 1.2 support, so just I removed my old virtualenv, and created a new one with the same packages and then it worked. Easy peasy!

**See also:**

- [The warning about TLS 1.0](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tls.html#python-3-x)) in the Python 3 section in the PyMongo documenation. Although it's under the Python 3 section it also applies to Python 2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and talked for 30 minutes with the Mongo Atlas support which deployed over AWS. I run the next terminal command:

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Please check if you are connected via VPN. when I disconnected it resolved my problem.

Comment: its better to say this kind of answer with comment to the question

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)